# Multiple response types for async gRPC client

Tags: c++, asynchronous, grpc

What is a pattern (some context POD) for handling different response types when we deal with single `CompletionQueue` within async gRPC client (C++)? I have a separate thread which calls `CompletionQueue::Next()`. P.S. I don't want to modify proto-file.